# Custom taxonomy link automatically removing query string and re-directing

Tags: custom-taxonomy, redirect

Example:

http://localhost/?categoryname=apples

is automatically redirecting to:

http://localhost/categoryname/apples/

This is making it difficult to sort by multiple categories: http://localhost/?categoryname=apples+oranges and sorting by multiple custom taxonomies.

Any idea why it would be auto re-directing? I've disabled all plugins and it still does it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress uses the `redirect_canonical` function in order to ensure that URLs are properly following the current permalink structure: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/redirect_canonical

The function is hooked to automatically run on the `template_redirect` filter. In order to remove it, you need to add the following snippet to your theme or plugin:

`remove_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );`

Keep in mind that this will allow a single page (in this case taxonomy index) to have multiple URLs, which is not good for SEO, because the following URLs will show the same content:

- http://localhost/categoryname/apples/
- http://localhost/categoryname/apples

WordPress will also not handle http://localhost/?categoryname=apples+oranges automatically, since its base logic only works with a single taxonomy. The best way to approach this issue would be to use custom rewrite rules and to introduce a new rewrite/query tag, for example `categories`, instead of the default `categoryname`. This however, is a topic that cannot be explained quickly and requires some research first.

Comment: Thanks. That did work but you are correct it no longer redirects the /apples to /apples/ . However with Yoast SEO installed it seems the canonical tag on both pages are /apples/ so would that not resolve the SEO issue?

Comment: Please :)

The issue is that search engines will find two pages with the same content and instead of a single page being ranked up, you would get the traffic split in two.

As for the canonical tag by WordPress SEO, that should actually fix the issue.